# почему у меня не работает запись в базу данных?

Tags: php, steam

У меня на сайте есть авторизация через Steam
но после авторизации меня перенаправляет на файл "steam_fail"
При этом запись в базу данных в таблицу users не происходит.

Помогите разобрать в чем проблема и устранить это.
Если кто знает в чем проблема и может исправить готов финансово отблагодарить.

вот код

```php
<?php
if(!isset($Functions)){
    die("Error! 404");
}

require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/engine/openid.php';

if($Functions->isLogged()){
    if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
        session_destroy();
    }
    $Functions->redirect();
}else{
    try{
        $openid = new LightOpenID('http://'.$Functions->config['site_name']);
        if(!$openid->mode) {
            if(isset($_GET['login'])){
                $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
                $Functions->redirect($openid->authUrl());
            }else{
                $Functions->redirect();
            }
        }elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel'){
            $Functions->redirect();
        }else{
            if($openid->validate()) {
                $id = $openid->identity;
                $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
                preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);
                $json_object = file_get_contents("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=".$Functions->config['steamapi']."&steamids=".$matches[1]);
                if($json_object == false){
                    die($Functions->getIndex("steam_fail"));
                }else{
                    $json_decoded = json_decode($json_object);
                    $player = $json_decoded->response->players[0];
                    if(!empty($player)){
                        $getPlayer = $Functions->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE steamid = '".$player->steamid."'");
                        if($getPlayer->num_rows == 0){
                            $Functions->db->query("INSERT INTO `users`(`steamid`, `name`, `avatar`, `money`, `created`, `status`) VALUES ('".$player->steamid."', '".$player->personaname."', '".$player->avatarfull."', '0', '".time()."', '1')");
                        }else{
                            $Functions->db->query("UPDATE users SET name = '".$Functions->getString($player->personaname)."', avatar = '".$player->avatarfull."' WHERE steamid = '".$player->steamid."'");
                            $_SESSION['name'] = $player->personaname;
                            $_SESSION['steamid'] = $player->steamid;
                            $_SESSION['avatarfull'] = $player->avatarfull;
                        }
                        $Functions->redirect();
                    }else{
                        die($Functions->getIndex("steam_fail"));
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $Functions->redirect();
            }
        }
    }catch(ErrorException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

если что то ещё нужно могу скинуть другие файлы

Comment: Ну просто у Вас не происходит декодирования ответа, а именно значения в нем players. Чтобы понять что там приходит - добавьте пожалуйста print_r($json_decoded) после части $json_decoded = json_decode($json_object); и добавьте ответ в Ваш вопрос. С радостью поможем.

Comment: stdClass Object ( [response] => stdClass Object ( [players] => Array ( ) ) )

то что я получай после использования print_r($json_decoded)

Comment: сам код подразумевает, что у Вас обязательно должны возвращаться пользователи, а именно обязательно должен существовать первый элемент в массиве players. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, сейчас у Вас код возвращает пустой массив, по этому происходит ошибка. Вам необходимо посмотреть что вообще возвращается - print_r($json_object), возможно там ошибка steam или по условиям Вашего запроса нет подходящих игроков.
Обратите внимание, что теперь обычный ответ еще до декодирования - json_object

Comment: могу ли я как то отправить вам архив чтоб вы посмотрели?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mQMOQXJDP2k_KSO2PlpI3rFDFdtonua_/view?usp=share_link


ЭТО ССЫЛКА НА АРХИВ СО ВСЕМИ ФАЙЛАМИ В ТОМ ЧИСЛЕ И БАЗОЙ ДАННЫХ

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)